# Where have all the related questions links gone?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, related-questions

Is it just me, or have the 'related questions' links gone AWOL today?

They were around earlier in the day (US/Pacific time), but aren't showing up on SO now (late evening).

As [PeterJ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1599751/peterj) observed in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270894/where-have-all-the-related-questions-links-gone#comment91441_270894), it is newer questions that are missing the links (at the moment).

For example:

- [I want to declare a pointer array to character without using string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718343/i-want-to-declare-a-pointer-array-to-character-without-using-string) — new (2014-09-08 06:15:08Z), no related questions listed.
- [Is `scanf` guaranteed not to change the value on failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715204/is-scanf-guaranteed-to-not-change-the-value-on-failure) — old (2014-09-07 22:05:53Z), some related questions listed.
- [Is `wget` distributed with all Unix platforms as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718100/is-wget-distributed-with-all-unix-platforms-as-default) — fairly new (2014-09-08 05:49:09Z), some related questions listed.

This suggests the break time might be 2014-09-08 06:00:00Z — hardly an exhaustive test, but indicative.

Comment: Seems to be newer questions, it still displays for older questions.

Comment: @PeterJ: Good observation — yes, new questions seem to be lacking the 'related questions' links, but older questions still have them.

Comment: "Newer" as in after midnight UTC, or "newer" as of a few moments ago?  [Because if it's the former, I can't reproduce it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717009/list-validation-in-drools)

Comment: Newer, as in very new — last half hour or so as I type. Note also an absence of related questions on this page (at the moment).

Comment: I was seeing this too, about thirteen hours ago (last time I was on the site).

Comment: Just for the record, by some time on 2014-09-10, and quite possibly earlier, related question links had turned up on this question.  It seems that there is now (recently) a more frequent delay between a question being asked and related question links being attached to it.

Comment: @Haney any chance that the generated when the title and tags are part of a question before it is posted can be put in as an *initial* related?  The lack of related questions makes it difficult to find the dups.  Click on post, look to the side, see dup in related, quickly close as a dup.  Now its click on post, wonder if there's a dup, search for dup, search again, search sucks, try google, found a post, close as dup... oh, there are already four FGITW answers from people...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not a bug, based on an [old answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65582/why-does-the-related-question-list-not-always-show-up/65588#65588) this seems to be [by-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69397/the-related-questions-panel-gone-on-stackoverflow-is-sometimes-missing). Not sure if it is still valid but the algorithm to find Related Posts is expensive. Sometimes for newer questions you may not see them immediately. For the posts mentioned above I can now see related posts.

Comment: It is curious that I'd not seen this before, but it seems a plausible explanation.  Thank you.

Comment: Hard to imagine why it is any more expensive than showing the list of related posts in the question composer. And that happens *on-the-fly* any time someone so much as *tries* to post a question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Usually the delay is not much, however I did see the section was missing on one of the post last week, so did some searching on MSE and found the possible reason.

Comment: @CodyGray If we're going to prioritise one over the other, it makes total sense to have the real-time on the fly one running at full pelt. If we can avoid questions being asked because OP finds the answer through the related question feature while writing it, that saves noise across the site *and* reduces load on the side-bar related list due to less questions being created.

Comment: Somehow I doubt this because I *feel* I always saw related questions even for new questions not long ago, since I usually find dupe target from there. But then, probably it was because of my fuzzy memory, and I couldn't proof it now anyway. And again, there is this answer, and the related questions are still not shown on this question.

Comment: @AndrewT. no, your memory serves you right. Related posts were added to new questions pretty quickly there was not much of a delay. Lately, a delay has jumped in, not sure what the reason is. Sooner or later, related posts are displayed on SO question. However, MSO looks to be broken.

Comment: @Polynomial: but the site has *already* built that list for the new question that's being asked before it was even posted. Caching it at that time should logically mean one doesn't need to be prioritized...

Comment: In addition to what Wooble said, I should clarify that I wasn't arguing we had our priorities backwards. Simply that if we can stomach running the queue there, it is hard to believe that it is too expensive to run *once* for all new questions.

Comment: The behaviuor has certainly changed recently, which this answer doesn't really address. Would be good to see a staff response on this one. I found the related question queue to be a very effective way of closing duplicates :-(