# Related posts are missing on Meta questions posted after 2014-09-10

Tags: support, meta, related-questions

On Meta, Related posts are not displayed on questions which were posted after 2014-09-10 00:53Z. On SO questions, related posts start showing up in an hour or so (there is a delay) but on MSO its been more than 2 days now. Earlier the script/query didn't run for 3 days from Sep7 till Sep10. There seems to be a delay but seems like the frequency is erratic or maybe the SE team now runs it manually.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this as a duplicate? The question *specifically explains* how this is a distinct issue. It's not like it's buried somewhere, the whole question is only 3 lines. You can't miss it.

Comment: I really want to see what people were voting to close this as a duplicate against.

Comment: @AdamJensen some believe (I think incorrectly) that this is a duplicate of [Where have all the related questions links gone?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270894/839601) FWIW you could find it yourself, by trying flag -> close -> duplicate and checking what question is suggested there (just don't forget to cancel the flagging after that:)

Comment: Update: seems like either the query/script was broken or it died. It did run again at some point after I posted this question. Now questions posted before 2014-09-10 00:53Z have the related posts section (still missing for posts which were made after this timestamp. Earlier it stopped running on. I guess only SE team can provide an update on this. They maybe working on a new feature or fine-tuning the current one due to which the script/query now runs after some delay.

Comment: @gnat I learned something new today :)

Comment: @AzizShaikh - also I didn't see your later comment about the timestamp updating, so I think my comment is misleading. I'll remove it.

Comment: Note that it took several days for the proposed duplicate question ([Where have all the related questions links gone?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270894/)) to collect any related question links; it does now have some.  The two questions are extremely closely related and the underlying cause is the same; the only major difference is that this is for MSO and that was for SO.