# How can I show related questions?

Tags: support, related-questions

Sometimes, when I view a question, the page shows "Related" questions to the right. I can often find related questions there, and sometimes cast a duplicate vote according to that.

However, sometimes there aren't any "Related" questions - the relevant area just doesn't appear. What can I do to show that? Refreshing the browser page doesn't help.

I tried pasting the question title into the search bar; it worked, but not as well: "Related" questions show more information, and items there are more relevant. I verified it with another question, where both methods work.

As a [previous question on this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270894/where-have-all-the-related-questions-links-gone) says, related questions are more likely to be missing for newer questions. And also, there is some database query, which takes more than 1 second to execute (this is how I interpret ["related costs 1s+"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69397/the-related-questions-panel-gone-on-stackoverflow-is-sometimes-missing/69402#69402)). So there might be a method to run this query, if I really want to.

Comment: Keep in mind that this _“related costs 1s+”_ answer is 10 years old. We’ve had [recent issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350569/289905) with them, and the database cost may now be vastly different.

Comment: The title is actually "Related", not "related questions". I updated my post because there was confusion between "Related" and "Linked".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing related questions is entirely automatic - the system either shows it or not. If it doesn't, it is impossible to search the database for related questions manually.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is on the overmeta site; related questions are not specific to Stack Overflow.

[How are "related" questions selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected)

The implementation seems to change from time to time though, but since the last answer is from 2018, I am pretty sure that it is still accurate. the gist of it is: "it's automatic". And things that happen automatically will have varying results of success and relevance.

There are also linked questions - those are posts on the same site that have been linked to from posts or comments.

Comment: Does "it's automatic" mean "it's impossible to do this manually"?

Comment: @anatolyg that's what the linked questions are for

Comment: Related: [The “Related” section in the right sidebar is now completely missing for new questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352855/241919)